# Ubuntu hangs while booting

Tags: 11.04, boot

Yesterday i closed my PC properly. Today while booting, Ubuntu hangs after line:

```
Starting TiMidity++ ALSA midi emulation [OK]
```

I have these fail messages below, nothing else seems wrong:

```
Starting load fallback graphics devices [fail]
Stopping automatic crash report generation [fail]
```

I have tried updating grub menu and cleaning old packages and Linux headers but it did not work.

I can boot my PC in safe graphics mode. That cause me to suspect my graphics settings.

I am using Lenovo SL500 and HP Pavilion DV9087ea. Moving my disk between these two did not work.
It hangs at same boot stage in two computers.

Do you have any suggestion to inspect problem?

Lenovo graphics card:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G98 [GeForce 9300M GS] (rev a1)

HP graphics card:
nVidia GeForce 7600 Go

Comment: Please tell your graphic video card by tipying in a terminal:  
    lspci | grep -i vga

Comment: @OlcayErtaş Does this answer solves your trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this tutorial: http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/quick-and-easy-way-to-fix-x11-issues/

After that, if it works, use this Terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

And then reboot.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is wrong here. And how does this problem is fixed. I had the same trouble `Starting load fallback graphics devices [fail]` at booting. Thanks forward.

Comment: I tried follows this link but at terminal it prints that `command stop not found`

Comment: @nazar_art where does it say to run "stop"?

Comment: You should follow this link (at answer).

Comment: @nazar_art Yes, I wrote it =P I know it says `sudo service XYZ stop`, but I don't see where it says `sudo stop` or `stop` as a command... you may have written it wrong on the TTY (just print it or something like that, and then run it XD)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.